# jQuery DataTables: How to display what filters are being applied

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using a combination of https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html and https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

So someone can search for something, narrow down their results, go to another page, come back and not remember what the filters were previously

My ask is whether we can expose what current searches/filters are in place and for what columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The problem is that the search terms entered by users into each column heading are not restored when the saved state is restored (even though the search terms are re-applied to filter the DataTable). These fields are part of the DOM (not part of the underlying DataTable).

**Solution**

You need to take the following extra steps to retrieve these values from local storage and then re-display them in the HTML `<input>` fields, so the user can see them.

In the following DataTable, I am using the same [column filtering example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) as referenced in the question.

I have also added the `stateSave: true` option to my example, to recreate the problem described in the question.

**Steps to Fix**

```
var colSearches = [];
```

The above variable will hold an array of the column search terms entered by the user.

```
stateLoadParams: function (settings, data) {
    // capture any previously used column search terms:
    colSearches = [];
    data.columns.forEach( (col, idx) => {
        // The DataTables smart search wraps the search term in
        // parentheses - so remove them here:
        var searchTerm = col.search.search.slice(4, -4);
        colSearches.push( searchTerm );
      });
}
```

The above [`stateLoadParams`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadParams) option is used to populate my `colSearches` array. It retrieves each column search term from local storage. The `stateSave` option is already doing this, behind the scenes, for us - but we need to retrieve the saved data again here, so that we can manually re-populate the input fields.

Finally, I use the following code to restore the search terms into the relevant input fields in the column headings:

```
$('.filters th:nth-child(' + (colIdx+1) + ') input').val( colSearches[colIdx] );
```

The above line needs to be added to the existing `initComplete` function, after each `<input>` element is added to the table.

---

**Note**

There is a potential limitation with this approach. It assumes your column  [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) function is exactly the same as the one used in the demo example (and the code shown below). Specifically, the `regex` option must be `false` and the `smart` option must be `true` (which are the `search()` function's default values).

I have not tested the above approach with a customized `search()` function - for example, I suspect it may not work if you want to set the `regex` option to `true`.

---

For reference, here is the full code with some sample data, so you can see how the pieces fit together:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office in Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

<script>

var colSearches = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead tr')
        .clone(true)
        .addClass('filters')
        .appendTo('#example thead');
 
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        
        stateSave: true,
        
        stateLoadParams: function (settings, data) {
            // capture any previously used column search terms:
            colSearches = [];
            data.columns.forEach( (col, idx) => {
                // The DataTables smart search wraps the search term in
                // parentheses - so remove them here:
                var searchTerm = col.search.search.slice(4, -4);
                colSearches.push( searchTerm );
            });
        },
        
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();
 
            // For each column
            api
                .columns()
                .eq(0)
                .each(function (colIdx) {
                    // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                    var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                        $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                    );
                    var title = $(cell).text();
                    $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
                    
                    // Restore the previously used search term:
                    $('.filters th:nth-child(' + (colIdx+1) + ') input').val( colSearches[colIdx] );
 
                    // On every keypress in this input
                    $(
                        'input',
                        $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                    )
                        .off('keyup change')
                        .on('keyup change', function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
 
                            // Get the search value
                            $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                            var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();
 
                            var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                            // Search the column for that value
                            api
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(
                                    this.value != ''
                                        ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                        : '',
                                    this.value != '',
                                    this.value == ''
                                )
                                .draw();
 
                            $(this)
                                .focus()[0]
                                .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                        });
                });
        }
                
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```